# Highchart heatmap: exclude the total row for color Axis

Tags: highcharts

I'am using highchart for create a heatmap with total row:

[Highchart heatmap with total row](https://jsfiddle.net/ttthhhcg/6L39skb4/1/)

The data sample:

```
[
   [0, 0, 30], 
   [0, 1, 15], 
   [0, 2, 10], 
   [0, 3, 5], 
   [1, 0, 50], 
   [1, 1, 20], 
   [1, 2, 10], 
   [1, 3, 20]
]
```

Total row is `[0, 0, 30]` and `[1, 0, 50]`

But for now maxColor is assigned to cell `[1, 0, 50]` under total row.

How can I make the maxColor is assigned to `[1, 1, 20]` cell?

Like this image:

[image]

Please help me, thank you.

Comment: if you want to set maxColor for `[1, 1, 20]` then what about `[1,0,50]`

Comment: ```[1,0,50]``` is under total row., I want make the total row to other color. @Udhay Titus

Comment: are you trying something like this http://jsfiddle.net/d_paul/ktjmc46v/

Comment: actually I want it like this: https://i.ibb.co/GtbnYKg/2019-06-10-16-49.png. I've update the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `colorAxis.max` to `20` and change the color individually for the 'total' points:

```
colorAxis: {
    max: 20,
    ...
},

series: [{
    ...,
    data: [{x: 0, y: 0, value: 30, color: 'red'},
        [0, 1, 15],
        [0, 2, 10],
        [0, 3, 5],
        {x: 1, y: 0, value: 50, color: 'red'},
        [1, 1, 20],
        [1, 2, 10],
        [1, 3, 20]
    ]
}]
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ue13kfmc/

**API:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/colorAxis.max